# NHibernate - How to properly handle One-to-Many references in code

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lazy-loading, one-to-many, lazy-initialization

What it the proper way to handle One-to-Many on the code side with NHibernate, keeping in mind that our collection could be huge (lets say 400 000 references)

Currently in my application, I handle them with ISet this way:

```
public class Questionnaire: BaseDatabaseModel{
    public Questionnaire()
    {
        _questions = new HashSet<Question>()
    }

    private readonly ISet<Question> _questions;
    public virtual IEnumerable<Question> Questions{
        get{return _questions;}
    }

    public virtual void AddQuestion(Question q){
        if(_questions.Add(q)){
            q.Questionnaire = this;
        }
    }

    public virtual void RemoveQuestion(Question q){
        if(_questions.Remove(q)){
            q.Questionnaire = null;
        }
    }
}

public class Question: BaseDatabaseModel{

    private Questionnaire _questionnaire;
    public virtual Questionnaire Questionnaire { 
        get{
            return _questionnaire;
        } 
        set{

            if (_questionnaire.IsNotNull() && _questionnaire != value)
            {
                // remove previous reference since it changed
                _questionnaire.RemoveQuestion(this);
            }

            if (value.IsNotNull())
            {
                // Add new reference if not null
                value.AddQuestion(this);
            }

            // Set value
            _questionnaire = value;
        } 
    }
}
```

This works great to make sure entities reference in my session are always correct, the problem is when my collection is not initialized and set to lazyload, nhibernate will initialize the whole collection just to add or remove my entity, resulting in poor performance in some cases (mainly when using filters on lazyloaded collections)

What would be the best/recommended way to handle cases like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this reference for collection from your class.
If you need some object from collection you can get that object (or few object) by querying table collection from repository (by id of object from collection or id of base class).
Add and remove methods can be executed by repository.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I'm also using NHibernate Envers, which requires to have the reference mapped. I think that I read somewhere that we can handle situations like this by handling the save by the child only with Inverse relation, without having to add the relation to the parent. That way I wouldn't need to initialize the parent. The thing I don't like about this is that sometime we can insert bugs if we forget that we didn't add the reference to the parent and we are still handling the instance in memory.

Comment: It seems to me that, and so you become pagination collection forms to the user.
Because these data are too many to display them.
So writing from the child and adding methods to the factory that requires a parent will not be a problem.